# How to get the node a jstree context menu was triggered on?

Tags: javascript, jstree

Trying to get a **jstree** **contextmenu** up to trigger node-specific actions. Very helpful for starters: [Doc to jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu&f=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items)

Sadly, one of the most interesting points is incomplete: What parameters are served to the `action` function assigned? Doing experiments, I already found it apparently has only one parameter (at least parameter 2 was `undefined`).

I progressed to connect `action` to

```
function action_on_context(data)
{
    let s = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, val) { s+=key + '=>' + Object.keys(val) + ', '});
    console.log("Context Action: " + s);
}
```

Which yields me

```
Context Action:
  item => icon,label,title,action,
  reference => 0,length,prevObject,
  element => 0,length,
  position => x,y,
```

- *item*: As the name says, just the config I gave to the menu option.
- *reference*: Appears to relate to the link connected to the node.
- *element*: Apparently is the li tag of the context menu option itself.
- *position*: Is this the x,y mouse coordinates?

So far **reference** is my best hunch:

```
console.log(data.reference.attr('id'));
```

logs me the id of the anchor that seems to equal **<tree_node_id_the_context_menu_was_opened_on>_anchor**.

The question boils down to: **"Is there a better way to obtain the node the context menu was opened on?"**

Answer (score 0):

I think, I can answer my own question:

**reference** actually is the anchor embedded within the **<li>** that defines the HTML making up the tree entry the context menu was opened upon.

Thus this parenting **<li>** element holds the `id` attribute of the tree node. And since `reference` is presented as a JQuery object, all I need is the jquery command

```
data.reference.parent().attr('id');
```